# AsyncFunction Error using create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, async-await, create-react-app

I'm experiencing a weird error using `create-react-app`:

when using `AsyncFunction` constructor to create an async function, it works during development but not works after build.

Below code runs fine in development, but will throws an error **`await is only valid in async function`**.

I tried logging `AsyncFunction` in production build, and it became `function{ native code }` not `async function {native code }` 
I think it has something to do with babel transpiler, but I don't know how to fix this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
    const AsyncFunction  = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
    let func = new AsyncFunction('await otherAsync()')
    func();
```

Comment: I've had the same error. I assume it's a babel issue but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround. Clearly Babel is doing something to rewrite AsyncFunction in terms of older browser primitives. My workaround is to wrap the function in a regular function marked 'async'.  My generated code looks like this:

```js
{
    const add = scope.add
    // ... everything else I want in scope
    const chart = scope.chart
    const histogram = scope.histogram
    const timeline = scope.timeline
    async function foos() { 
      return await dataset('elements')
    }
    return foos()
}
```

In the code above there's an invisible variable called 'scope' which it uses to define local vars.  Then it returns a hard coded async function `foos()` which contains the actual code to be evaluated: `return await dataset('elements')`

I can run this with the following. `gen_code` is a string containing the above generated code.

```js
try {
    let func = new Function('scope',gen_code)
    return func(scope)
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    return e
}
```

I think that will do it.